# mysql select order issue

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table like that

```
id  UserID      score   create_time     
7   002YEXEKF9  120000  2013-06-06 14:04:52     
8   0008FV2FN5  120     2013-06-06 15:10:39             
9   0008FV2FN5  130     2013-06-06 16:57:27             
10  DT5LP0V8AH  1200    2013-06-06 15:13:44         
11  DT5LP0V8AH  1400    2013-06-06 16:31:03
```

I use this query for select data:

```
SELECT userid, score FROM high_score ORDER BY score DESC
```

The result:

```
userid      score 
002YEXEKF9  120000
DT5LP0V8AH  1400
DT5LP0V8AH  1200
0008FV2FN5  130
0008FV2FN5  120
```

As you can see that user_id DT5LP0V8AH,0008FV2FN5 has two score.I don't want this.I want show the highest score of users.
All I want the result like this:

```
userid      score 
002YEXEKF9  120000
DT5LP0V8AH  1400
0008FV2FN5  130
```

Can anyone fix the sql?.I really appreciate.

Comment: Try `SELECT userid, max(score) as score FROM high_score GROUP BY userid ORDER BY score DESC`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `MAX()` to get the highest score and `GROUP BY` aggregate function to group by `userid`

```
SELECT userid, MAX(score) 
FROM high_score 
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `MAX`, `GROUP BY` to get the result you wanted to.

```
SELECT userid, MAX(score) 
FROM high_score 
GROUP BY userid ORDER BY score DESC
```

Find more info on [MAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group.html).

Find more info on [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group.html)

I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (Haven't tested).

```
SELECT  userid, MAX(score) max_score FROM high_score GROUP BY userid ORDER BY max_score DESC
```